# Kivymd App on Android has different colour icons to my Mac

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I compiled the KivyMD app I've been coding onto my phone and I had to specify in the `buildozer.spec requirements` to use `sdl2_ttf==2.0.15` for the MD icons to actually appear. However, all the icons are fully white even though they have a text colour set to `0, 0, 0, 1`:

```
MDFloatingActionButton:
    icon: 'plus-circle-outline'
    elevation_normal: 10
    user_font_size: '20sp'
    text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8, 'y': 0.03}
    on_release: app.CreateNewWorkout_1_Dialog()
```

On my Mac:

[image]

On my phone:

[image]

It also changes some of the text on buttons and in MDTextFields. I thought it had something to do with the `sdl2_ttf==2.0.15` and tried other versions but the icons would only appear on this version. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when compiling, you are using the KivyMD library from the PyPi and not from the master branch.

This is a bug in the library. Do not use the value 0, 0, 0, 1. If you need a black icon color, you can set the value to 0, 0, 0, 0.9:

```
MDFloatingActionButton:
    text_color: 0, 0, 0, .9
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8, 'y': 0.5}
```

Comment: This is my buildozer.spec file: `requirements: python, kivy==2.0.0,git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15`. Is the kivymd requirement not from the master branch?

Comment: All your `requirements` are irrelevant after the first build.
They are cached. Therefore, before building, you need to delete the `.buildozer` directory.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that, that's the `rm -rf .buildozer` where your buildozer.spec file is isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that now.

Answer (score 0):

Because when compiling, you are using the KivyMD library from the PyPi and not from the master branch.

This is a bug in the library. Do not use the value 0, 0, 0, 1. If you need a black icon color, you can set the value to 0, 0, 0, 0.9: